# JavaScript: Hide button link if input field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to hide a button link (id="btnsubmit") whenever the input field (id="valagency") is empty, so that my user can only click on the button after the input field is filled with some data.

For the html part, I have

```
<tr>
 <td class="tbldatastart">
  <input type="text" id="**valagency**" name="agencyname<%= strAgencyId %>" class="btn10" readonly> 
  <input type="text" name="agencyid<%= strAgencyId% >"> 
  <a href="javascript:Map('<%= strAgencyId %>');" class="btn1">Map</a>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2"></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:Submit()" id="btnsubmit" class="btn1">Submit</a></td>
</tr>
```

And for the javascript, I have

```
function Submit() {

  $("#valagency").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()) {
        $("#btnsubmit").show();
    } else {
        $("#btnsubmit").hide();
    }

  });
}
```

The submit button is still there. I do not know where I did wrongly. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the keyup should be outside the Submit() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling function submit at that time your enable disable button code will execute.

you need to use that code independently not on submit call.

Place following code out of submit function:

```
$("#valagency").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        $("#btnsubmit").show();
    } else {
        $("#btnsubmit").hide();
    }
});
```

If you want to disable submit on submit button click how it's possible when you've used `keyup` event.

If you want to do so on submit button click then you need to use `keyup`.

If you want to use `keyup` then code will be outside of `submit` function.

Keyup will not work on pasting data to input.
For that consider [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/m06yywmn/1/)  example.

```
<input type="text" name ="mytxt" id="mytxt"> 
<a href="#" id="btnsubmit" class="btn1">Submit</a>


$('input[name=mytxt]').change(function() { 
if($(this).val() == "") {        
        $("#btnsubmit").hide();
    } else {
        $("#btnsubmit").show();
    }
});
```

If you want to hide button on page load then you can go with https://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/m06yywmn/2/

Comment: my pleasure. post me if any issue.

Comment: Consider using `input` or `change` instead of `keyup`. It supports things like pasting code, drag-and-drop, and Android keyboards that don't report key actions correctly.

Comment: @SamR: thanks for suggestion. Yes you're right keyup will not work on copy paste of data. For that `change` method works well.

Comment: Does keyup work well with parsing data from child window? Since the data in the input field will be parsed from child window.

Comment: Nope, I am posting new example which will work on pasting data. Wait for 2-3 minutes please.

Comment: @user3145373ツ, the submit button is not hided on page load.

Comment: @BrianCheong: as you said you want this on input element, I have added it on input not on page load. If you want to do so then you have to implement same thing on page load.

Comment: @BrianCheong: added another example link. Check it. If you've got solution then mark answer as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're running your `keyup()` function on click of the submit button. This will never execute. Simply move your `keyup()` function outside of this button click. You'll also want to hide `#btnsubmit` by default.

Here's a minimal example:

```js
$("#btnsubmit").hide();
$("#valagency").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $("#btnsubmit").show();
  } else {
    $("#btnsubmit").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="valagency">
<a href="#" id="btnsubmit" class="btn1">Submit</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keyup event, use change event to get the final value of input field and check for it's emptiness.

Answer (score 0):

It's just related with input keyup event, so If you want to check the input's value to hide/show the button. make it independent with 'submit', it should be hide/show before the 'submit'.

```
function submit() {
  //do something
}
$("#valagency").keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "") {
      $("#btnsubmit").show();
  } else {
      $("#btnsubmit").hide();
  }
});
```